# Product not returning it's short description

Tags: product, blocks, template

in a template I am calling function in a block using:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
<?php echo $this->getProductEncode($_product); ?>
```

The function  getProductEncode then returns some json-ld encoded text.  However, when I use this function:

```
$description = $product->getShortDescription();
```

Nothing is description is set to " '' ".  Why is this?  If I remember correctly, short descriptions IS part of products, right?  I looked in our backend and it's definitely set for the product in question.  Is there a workaround available?

I don't understand why magento instantiates only minutely different implementations of a 'product' seemingly at random.

```
Mage::log($product->debug(), null, 'testing.log', true);
```

Does not display short description as part of this product.  Other areas of my store use the above getShortDescription() on product to retrieve it.

Comment: Assuming that your using $_product and not $product, is this a single or multi store?

Comment: Are you missing the ()? And as R.S. already started to say, are you sure, the value is set correctly in the store view?

Comment: @R.S when a user visits the product page I am calling the above registry mage function which then passes the product to the function described in the block.  Multi store.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I added the () to the question. And added additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong,

```
$description = $product->getShortDescription
```

Without the parenthesis, you are trying to access a variable called `getShortDescription`, not call the method `getShortDescription()`, it should be,

```
$description = $product->getShortDescription()
```

---

**Now that you've edited you question ...**

Your code is *still* wrong, you are instantiating the model and storing it in a variable called `$_product`

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

But then you are trying to access a non-defined variable called `$product`

```
$product->getShortDescription();
```

You should use,

```
$_product->getShortDescription(); 
 ^
 |
Note the underscore!
```

Comment: Yea, I had the ().  I'll edit my question.

Comment: Answer updated to suit edited question.

Comment: I am passing $_product from a template file to a block.  The function getProductEncode($product) could just as well be defined as getProductEncode($sponge) or getProductEncode($notAProduct).  The result would still be me passing $_product to getProductEncode($___) and then using that parameter to call $___->getShortDescription().  Which, just as originally described, does not return the $_product's short description.

Comment: Read my answer, you assigned the class instance to `$_product` - but then later tried to access it with `$product`. You are trying to access a variable that ***has not been defined***

Comment: <?php Mage::log($_product->debug(), null, 'testing.log',true);?>
 shows no short description either.